# How Can I distribute 150 "attacks" on 10 people with a limit of 15 attacks per member

Tags: uniform-distribution

The title is understandably weird because its related to a game.
In a game mode I am in a team and I have 9 other team members so the team consists on 10 people.
The enemy team also has 10 people on their team and we are supposed to "attack" them, but there is a limit to the number of attacks a single member has which is 15 attacks, also 1 team member of mine cant attack a single enemy more the 5 times so, we are trying to distribute it with each member of our team getting 3 members, attacking each one of them 5 times but sometimes it doesn't work so I need a formula [Never mind the arrow in the picture above, the yellow box is the important thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsMay.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have ally player $i$ attack enemy player $j$ whenever $j-i$ is $1,2$ or $3\pmod{10}$. Explicitly:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
  \text{Ally player}&\text{Target 1}&\text{Target 2}&\text{Target 3}\\
  \hline
  1&2&3&4\\
  2&3&4&5\\
  3&4&5&6\\
  4&5&6&7\\
  5&6&7&8\\
  6&7&8&9\\
  7&8&9&10\\
  8&9&10&1\\
  9&10&1&2\\
  10&1&2&3\\
\end{array}$$